# Image is not inserting in CKEditor while scayt is enabled

Tags: ckeditor, scayt

I am using CKEditor version 4.4.2. My problem is that Image is not inserting in CKEditor while scayt is enabled by doing following steps.

Click on Source icon on toolbar,

Insert following HTML

`<div>Click here!</div>`

Click on Source icon on toolbar

Enable scayt from toolbar

Insert image from file (Please note that cursor position should be after “Click” text)

image is not inserting in text editor

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem on the [demo of the latest CKEditor version](http://ckeditor.com/demo), so you should do the following:

- Check if it works on the demo page, too (in case you missed some steps in your description).
- If you cannot reproduce it either, [upgrade your CKEditor installation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_upgrade) (current version is 4.4.7).
- Check your configuration and/or update your post with some more details such as your build config, custom plugins, environment, file browser used etc.

Comment: Thanks Anna for your reply,
Actually I am using Kentico CMS and Kentico CMS is using CKEditor 4.4.2 with some custom configuration. I have tried to update latest version of CKEditor 4.4.7 (Kentico is not supporting CKEditor version 4.4.7) and I face some ripples.

Kindly suggest me that how can I fix that bug in CKEditor 4.4.2

Comment: Sorry to say that but the way to fix this bug in CKEditor 4.4.2 is to apply patches from CKEditor 4.4.3, 4.4.4, etc... in other words - upgrading CKEditor ;). You can try to find the single patch which fix this issue and apply only this one , but it is very time consuming and it will still mean one thing - that you need to be able to apply it. And I think that upgrading is simpler anyway.

Comment: BTW. You should report this to the Kentico developers and ask them why they still haven't upgraded CKEditor. 4.4.2 is exactly one year old.